# Creating an array with only the Nth element of another array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, yahoo-finance

I am pulling data from Yahoo Finance and trying to build two arrays. One with the 1-week close of a stock and another one with only the close of the 50th week of the first one.

With that, I want to end up with a 1W Close column and a 50W Close column with the closes of every 50th thus the other ones can be Na/NaN.

I did:

```
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np

# Pull weekly and daily data 
base_data_daily = yf.download("AAPL",interval="1d")
base_data_weekly = yf.download("AAPL", interval="1wk")

# Create the 1W Close column and pass the weekly data
base_data_daily["1W Close"] = base_data_weekly["Close"]

# Show the table on Jupyter notebook
base_data_daily
```

This piece of code gives me this:

[image]

After that, I did:

```
weekly_closes = base_data_daily["1W Close"].to_frame().dropna()

#Show the table on Jupyter notebook
weekly_closes
```

and ended up with:

[image]

Now, here is where I got stuck. I want a similar table as the first one when the 1W Close skips days in between and prints the end of the week close.

As mentioned, I want to skip every 50 weeks close and print those closes in this 50W Close column.

I tried something like:

```
i = 50 
while i > len(weekly_closes["1W Close"]):
if i >= 50:
    weekly_closes["50W Close"][i]= weekly_closes["1W Close"][i]
else:
    weekly_closes["50W Close"][i]= weekly_closes["1W Close"][i]
    i+=50

#Show the table on Jupyter notebook
weekly_closes.head(60)
```

But I am getting the 50th printed correctly and the 49th data printed everywhere.

[image]

Comment: what is `yf`? add its definition code

Comment: You could use pandas [`.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html): `weekly_closes.resample("50W").last()`

Comment: Or you could slice with an interval of 50: `weekly_closes.iloc[::50]`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest fixed, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Rawson your second comment did the job after I deleted the if statement and only used `weekly_closes["50W Close"] = weekly_closes["1W Close"].iloc[::50]`. Thank you for that.